# Ordered notification of threads waiting on a condition (C++, boost)

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

Does anyone know of a condition variable class that allows notification of threads waiting for a condition to be notified in the order in which they started waiting?

I'm currently using the boost class `condition_variable`, but calling `condition_variable::notify_one()` wakes up a random thread, not the thread that first called `condition_variable::wait()`. I also tried adding thread ids to a queue before calling `condition_variable::wait()`, so that I can call `condition_variable::notify_all()` upon which all waiting threads wake up, check the queue and either wait again or proceed (only one thread, namely the thread first in queue). The problem is that calling `notify_all()` twice does not guarantee that all threads are waking up twice, thereby losing notifications. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strange that you require threads to be woken in particular order and sounds suspicious about your design. Anyway idea is that you can have queue of condition variables (one per thread) and you would call `notify_one()` for one from top of the queue. In waiting thread you  need to do additional logic to check that it was not sporadically interrupted from wait. Again sounds strange why you need thread to wake up in particular order and you may want to rethink your design.

Comment: Yes that would work I suppose, but you're right, it might be a design issue. I have a single thread that handles serial port reading/writing in an event loop. This loop also checks write events that I signal myself from different threads. These threads now wait for a response and the first response belongs to the thread that caused the first write event, hence the ordered signaling I was asking for.

Comment: Your overall design is borken, as described by @Slava